# Text processing to extract structure fields

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I am trying to extract fields from a structure, for example.

```
  typedef struct newstruct {
  long id;            
  uint32_t vtid;      
  struct HN* next;
} HashNode;
```

I want to use sed/awk to extract structure name, followed by the fields with a delimiter as

```
newstruct HashNode: long id, uint_32 vtid, struct HN* next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward with `awk`, perhaps doable with `sed`.

With `awk`, you would have a state that gets set/reset on each `typedef` line, and concludes on each line with a right curly brace.  A suitable `awk` script would look like

```
BEGIN {
    state = 0;
    typedef="";
    fields="";
}
/typedef[ ]+struct/{
    state = 1;
    typedef=$3;
    next;
}
/}.*;/ {
    if (state != 0) {
        sub("^.*}[  ]*","",$0);
        sub(";","",$0);
        sub(",$","",fields);
        printf "%s %s: %s\n", typedef, $0, fields;
        state = 0;
        fields = "";
        typedef = "";
    }
    next;
}
(state == 1){ 
    gsub("[     ]+"," ", $0);
    gsub(";",",",$0);
    fields = fields $0;
    next;
}
```

where the `[` and `]` brackets enclose a space and tab (to make it portable).  There are four parts to the script:

1. the `BEGIN` action initializes variables (not strictly necessary, but some awks do slightly different things with uninitialized variables)
2. the pattern matching the line with `typedef`, followed by blank(s) and the word `struct`.  That expects at least 3 fields on the line, using the third as the name of the typedef.
3. a pattern to match the closing curly brace.  Just in case your file has other stuff in it, the action checks if `state` was set.  The `$0` is the current line.  The first substitution trims away everything before the word we're interested in, and the second trims away the semicolon following it.  The third substitution changes a comma after the `fields` variable that came from the 4th action (below), to an empty string.
4. a pattern matching all other lines *when* `state` is set.  Like the previous action, this uses substitution to trim away the parts not wanted, first by reducing multiple blanks to a single blank, and then changing the trailing semicolon to a comma.

Call that file `foo.awk`, and your input data `foo.in`, to use awk like this:

```
awk -f foo.awk <foo.in
```

If you wanted to match lines like this:

```
struct foo {
```

rather than

```
typedef struct foo {
```

then the pattern could be written

```
/^([  ]*typedef)?[  ]+struct[  ]+/{
```

(again, with a literal space and tab in the square brackets).  The parentheses mark a *group* and the question mark `?` says to repeat that zero-or-more times.  (The **`{`** on the line actually denotes the beginning of the *action*, but I left it there to match the line in the given script).

Further reading:

- [awk - pattern scanning and processing language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) (POSIX)
- [9.4 Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (POSIX)

Comment: That is a very neat and flexible solution (taking into account possible multiple white spaces is thoughtful), but would it not be simpler to set `RS="typedef"` and `FS=";|{"` ? You can then directly loop on your fields with `printf` and send `next` when `$i == /^[ ]*}.*;`. Not sure this is worth a separate answer though.

Comment: Thanks Thomas !. Could you kindly explain the third step, I didn't fully understand it

Comment: How can I modify it to be generic: typedef struct newstruct or struct newstruct ? I modified 2nd part with /[typedef ]+struct/  but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -rn '
/typedef struct ([[:alnum:]_]+)\s+\{/!b
s//\1/; h
:X
n 
/}\s+([[:alnum:]_]+)/{
    s//\1/
    H
    g
    s/;//g
    s/(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)/\1 \5: \2, \3, \4/
    p;b
}
s/\s*(.+);\s*/\1/
H
bX
' file

newstruct HashNode: long id, uint32_t vtid, struct HN* next
```